# Angular - Foreach list string concact

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to know how to remove the "," from the last record of the vector. Because it prints as follows:
Skill Name: Skill 1, Skill 2, Skill 3,
The correct thing would be to print as follows:
Skill Name: Skill 1, Skill 2, Skill 3

```
list(skillSelect) {
    let naneSkil = "";
    
    arrayList.forEach((skill, index) => {
      if(skil.code === skillSelect.code) {
          nameSkill += skill.name.concat(', ');   
      }
    });
    
    return nameSkill;
  }
```

Comment: nameskill = arrayList.filter( skill => skill.code === skilSelect.code).join(‘,’);

Answer (score 0):

Before the return just write `nameSkill = nameskill.substr(0, nameskill.length - 2)`.
You're basically taking a substring of the original one.
In the function you pass the starting point nd the ending point.

In your case you don't want the last two characters, so you start from the very beginning of the word (`0`) and you finish at the end minus 2 (`nameskill.length-2`)

Documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Be aware that there is another function that does the same thing.
Check this question for this argument: What is the difference between substr and substring?

Comment: Please explain what this answer is doing, so questioner can learn something from it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a safe solution would be to use the join method on arrays, therefore you need to make the naneskill an array instead of a string. The join will never add the ',' to the last item

```
list(skillSelect) {
  let naneSkill = [];
    
  arrayList.forEach(skill => {
    if(skill.code === skillSelect.code) nameSkill.push(skill.name);
  });
    
  return nameSkill.join(',');
}
```